# Define new align environment based on the old one

Tags: formatting, environments

I am aware that there are plentiful similar questions, but since (even after several reading) I don't understand the the answers, I am unable to apply them to my problem.  I simply want to define a new align environment based on the old one, e.g.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,colframe=black,arc=8pt,boxrule=1pt}}
\newenvironment{alignteo}%
  {
  \begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{align}
  }{
  \end{empheq}
  }

\begin{alignteo}
f = a x
\end{alignteo}

\end{document}
```

Using `\begin{alignteo}` and `\end{alignteo}` I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{empheq} on input line 448 ended by \end{alignteo}.
```

Is there any way to do this without using `environ` package?

Comment: Can you make a complete example?

Comment: OK, I'll try to build MWE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `environ`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[svgnames,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,
  colframe=red!60!black,colback=yellow!50!white,arc=4pt,boxrule=1pt,
  drop fuzzy shadow}}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{alignteo}{
  \begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{align}
  \BODY
  \end{empheq}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath{E = mc^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\begin{alignteo}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{alignteo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `environ`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[svgnames,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,
  colframe=red!60!black,colback=yellow!50!white,arc=4pt,boxrule=1pt,
  drop fuzzy shadow}}

\newenvironment{alignteo}%
  {\empheq[box=\tcbhighmath]{align}}
  {\endempheq}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath{E = mc^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\begin{alignteo}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{alignteo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Requested was *without* *environ*...  Just turn the answers around :)

Comment: @Pygmalion My eyes are too tired. Any way both are there. Does order matter? :-)

Comment: Nope :) accepted +1